# libcurl send/receive multithread issue

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, libcurl

So I've joined a project that is depending on server-client socket communication. The idea is to continuosly check for messages from the server and then handle them while sometimes sending info on my own. I've been presented with following code:

```cpp
bool OnlineServerHandler::connectToServer(){
    /* some unrelated code here */
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl){
        /* some connection options and error checking */
        int threadCode;
        if((threadCode=pthread_create(&networkThread, NULL, OnlineServerHandler::readDataInLoop, NULL))!=0){
            CCLog("Failed to initialize new thread. Code: %d", threadCode);
            curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
            return false;
    }
    /* and more unrelated code here */
}

/* and method called in pthread_create */
void* OnlineServerHandler::readDataInLoop(void* threaddata){
    for(;;){
        if(exitThread) // flag to end the thread
            break;
        char buf[1024];
        wait_on_socket(sockfd, 1, 60000L);
        if(buf!=NULL && strlen(buf)>0)
            memset(&buf, 0, strlen(buf));
        res = curl_easy_recv(curl, buf, 1024, &iolen);
        if(CURLE_OK != res)
             continue;
        /* message processing */
    }
}
```

Problem is, from what I read about libcurl, it's a bad idea to use one handle in multiple threads. Here one handle handles message sending and receiving.

So my question is. Is there any way to divide data transport in libcurl? One handle would be only sending data, the other only receiving. I tried duplicating the handle but I wasn't able to receive data after sending some with original handle. Then I tried putting a flag to send data so that readDataInLoop() method would be also sending data but it doesn't work (I suspect curl_easy_recv() is keeping the thread for very long time if server is not sending anything). I don't think there is native option for it in libcurl (but then again, I'm often pretty brain blind).

Ofcourse any good idea will be welcomed provided that it uses libcurl (decision is not mine).

EDIT:
In the end I rebuilt whole connection code and put everything in one thread. Since I don't know how to close the question other way than answering it (and while issue is solved for now it's not really what I was looking for) I'll leave it open. Feel free to close this if you're a mod.

Comment: Looks to me like that code is based on this: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/multithread.html - my point being that multithreading isn't prohibited by cURL you just need to be careful. I didn't see your question at the bottom - just reading that now

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-multi.html it provides a non blocking implementation of the cURL api which will allow you to avoid the long waits. You will need to implement the asynchronous mechanism yourself, but it will allow that at least.

Comment: I don't think will allow what I want. In the end I rebuilt whole connection code and put everything in one thread.